# How do I replace all the spaces in just a substring of certain lines in a file?

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, perl

I have 3000 Markdown files named "journal/*.md", some of which contains file links like this:

```
blah blah text [Label here](file:///path/to file/may contain/spaces)
```

I want to change all such lines in such files to have %20 in the file:// URLs:

```
blah blah text [Label here](file:///path/to%20file/may%20contain/spaces)
```

This gets me almost there, by stovepiping:

```
for file in */*md; do if grep -l '(file:.*[ ].*)' "$file"; then echo FOUND in $file; sed 's?\((file://.*[ ].*)\)?\nREPLACED_SED1 \1?g' "$file" > "$file".sed1; sed '/REPLACED_SED1/s/ /%20/g' "$file".sed1 > "$file".sed2; fi; done
```

This leaves me with a Frankenfile that has the line split like this:

```
blah blah text [Label here]
REPLACED_SED1(file:///path/to%20file/may%20contain/spaces)
```

I'm stuck because how can I glue two lines together?  perl to the rescue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a one-run-attempt by using the hold space to apply a replacement to only a part of a line:

```
sed 'h;s/.*(file://;s/ /%20/g;x;s/(file:.*//;G;s/\n/(file:/'
```

1. Copy the line to the `h`old space. We will later use this for the first part of the line
2. Remove everything up to the splitting pattern: `s/.*(file://`
3. Do the replacement: `s/ /%20/g`
4. E`x`change buffers so we can work on the first part
5. Now remove the second part, starting from the pattern: `s/(file:.*//`
6. `G`: Join both parts by appending the hold space with the second part to the pattern space with the first part
7. Now replace the newline (which got embedded by appending) with the dividing pattern (which we removed from both parts): `s/\n/(file:/`

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*\(file:)(.*)(\).*)/,a) { gsub(/ /,"%20",a[2]); $0=a[1] a[2] a[3] } 1' file
blah blah text [Label here](file:///path/to%20file/may%20contain/spaces)
```

You can do the same using any awk with `match()`+`substr()`, it's just a few more characters typing:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/\(file:.*\)/) { tgt=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/ /,"%20",tgt); $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) } 1' file
blah blah text [Label here](file:///path/to%20file/may%20contain/spaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for file in */*md; do 
    while grep -l '(file:.*[ ].*)' "$file"; do
        sed -i 's/\(.*file:[^)]*\) \(.*\)/\1%20\2/' "$file"
    done
done
```

Explanation:

- while there is a space in the filename (your own grep), do
- divide the line in three parts: before the space, space and after the space
- replace with the first part, '%20' and the third part.

Because only one space per line gets replaced at the time, you need to loop. So as an example:

```
input:         blah blah text [Label here](file:///path/to file/may contain/spaces)
1st iteration: blah blah text [Label here](file:///path/to file/may%20contain/spaces)
2nd iteration: blah blah text [Label here](file:///path/to%20file/may%20contain/spaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep` and `xargs` and with `perl`:

```
grep --include='*.md' -rlZ '(file://[^)]* .*)' . |
  xargs -r0 perl -pi -e 's{\(file://.*?\)}{$& =~ s/ /%20/gr}ge'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tweaked your code and removed the second invocation of sed as it's unnecessary.

```bsh
for f in ./*/*md; do
  # select a nonlinked, regular, nonempty file

  [ ! -L "$f" ] &&
  [   -f "$f" ] && 
  [   -s "$f" ] &&
  < "$f" grep -q '(file://.*[ ].*)' ||
  continue

  echo "FOUND in $f"

  sed -e ':a
    s#\((file://.*\)[ ]\(.*)\)#\1%20\2#
    t a
  ' < "$f" > "$f.modif" &&
  mv -f "$f.modif" "$f"

done
```